# Como usar o javascript sem caixas de diálogos?

Tags: javascript, html

Eu quero pedir uma informação ao usuário só que sem usar aquelas caixas de diálogos e sim deixar impresso lá no site, com o uso do input. É com o javascript que se faz isso? Tentei pesquisar algo no google e eu não achei nada. Eu quero muito poder programar meu site, mas eu não faço ideia de por onde começar a aprender, ou coisa do tipo. Se tiverem uma dica eu agradeço.

Obs.: Este é um exemplo do que eu estou tentando fazer,já que eu não expliquei tão bem... 
Obs2.: Eu li o que vocês colocaram, só que pra pedi uma informação como essa, onde eu vou armazenar a resposta, eu não sei outra forma sem usar o prompt... Mas se eu usa-lo eu terei que usar o javascript, que consequentemente ele irá aparecer em uma caixa de diálogos.

[image: Exemplo:]

Comment: E por que não usa formulários?

Comment: Como assim ( eu sou leiga neste assunto ) Usar formularios no html ou no javascript?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp

Comment: Acho que esse é bastante esclarecedor: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/My_first_HTML_form

Comment: http://www.codecademy.com/#!/exercises/0 <- começa em HTML e evolui para Javascript

Comment: vlww.. vou dar uma olhada! :)

Comment: @VanessaCristina, se você deseja adicionar uma Pesquisa a sua pagina, talvez o ideal seja usar o [Google Forms](https://www.google.com/forms/about/), você tanto pode adicionar o mesmo dentro de um iFrame ou através da [API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se eu entendi bem o que você quer, mas pelo que eu li você quer dar uma mensagem ao usuário, em alguma posição na sua página que não seja por `alert()` ou algo parecido. Você pode usar o InnerHtml do javascript para isso, se é isso que eu estou entendendo. Com ele você dá a mensagem em uma determinada posição, como uma `<div>`, ou um `input text` e etc..., seria mais ou menos assim:
Defina uma área com um id de preferência. Essa área é onde você vai dar a mensagem. Vamos supor que seja de `id="txt_msg"`. Aí você faz:

```
function ExibeMensagem(pNomeParametroQualquer) {
    document.getElementById('txt_msg').innerHTML = 'Minha Mensagem';
}
```

No seu Form(web), você num evento qualquer, tipo `click` ou `change` do `textbox`, você chama a função:

```
<input button id="ffff" onclick="ExibeMensagem(qualquer_coisa)" />
```

Acho que foi isso que eu entendi o que você quer.

Answer (score 1):

Vejamos, você pode fazer um input e um botão submit, este que quando clicado (onClick) chamará uma função javascript que irá pegar os dados inseridos no input e fazer o que você deseja.
Lembrando que usando JavaScript o usuário poderá ver o código do seu script, então ele poderá saber todo o processo envolvendo o input.

Comment: [hide javaScript inside a image](http://www.patrick-wied.at/blog/a-technique-for-hiding-your-javascript-code) - tem gente que me espanda de tanta criatividade.

Comment: Uma vez eu dei uma resposta sem enviar código e quase me puniram por isso, transformaram a minha resposta em comentário, tive que retirar o "comentário" para evitar os downvotes. Jaedson, dê um exemplo à colega, só para a resposta entrar no padrão do SOpt.